# failed to open stream: No such file or directory in.. - Laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, fatal-error

I am currently working on Laravel project and I am trying to connect it to localhost
I am able to migrate and connect to it but whenever i open the link to preview it i get this:
[image]

the "public" folder was outside the project folder in "public_html" folder when i downloaded it from FTP and i copied "public_html" and paste it inside the project and renamed it to "public" and still having this issue

is there anything i need to change in .env file or somewhere else?

how can i solve this issue?

Comment: have you ran composer?

Comment: i updated it, nothing changed

Comment: why did you download this over FTP? Are you trying to create a dev site of a production site? If so, you should be using git to push to your production site. You should follow the installation guide in the official Laravel documentation.

Comment: the project isn't mine and the website owner lost contact with the previous developer and he don't know anything about the project or github link, what can i do?

Comment: log into the production server, go to the project root directory and see if git is installed and if there is a remote setup. `git remote -v` should tell you all you need to know. If you dont have access to that repo then create a new one and add it `git remote add origin {repo url}`, then git push origin. Origin is the name of the repo. It's the "go-to" name so if a remote exist it's probably already using it, so you'll need to create it with a different name. For example: `git remote add og {repo url}`

Comment: maybe your answer lies in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory greetings